# Receiving SOAP process with PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have read http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php over and over again. I don't understand if i should use SoapServer of SoapClient. It seems that my app should be the server. Trial and error didn't work for me this time.

The situation: a program sends every so many minutes data to the URL of my app. I figured out it receives data when I do `echo file_get_contents('php://input')`, which seems so stupid to start parsing this with `simplexml_load_string()`, or whatever (not that I managed).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope
```

....

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

...

```
    <SOAPSDK1:PostData xmlns:SOAPSDK1="http://tempuri.org/message/">      <tcXML>
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;ISO-8859-1&quot;?&gt;&lt;shop
```

I think this should be enough code to understand the concept. It is the part after `<tcXML>`, that I would like to be loaded into an PHP object.

Taking the example from PHP's documentation:

```
function test($x)
{
    return $x;
}

$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "http://test-uri/"));
$server->addFunction("test");
$server->handle();
```

I don't understand what URI I need to provide, since I just receive data?

Then I think: well then I need the SoapClient class, like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php",
                                     'uri'      => "http://test-uri/",
                                     'style'    => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                                     'use'      => SOAP_LITERAL));
```

Here I need to supply some `uri` or `location` again. I just cannot wrap my mind around it. Are these classes even used for this stuff? Am I asking even the right question here? Any guidance is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to **use (or consume)** someone elses `SOAP` web service, you use the `SoapClient` class.

When you want to **expose parts of your app** through a web service for **others to consume**, you use the `SoapServer` class.

In your situation, another process is sending your app data, **so you need to expose part of your application in order to receive** that data.  So you are right - you could use the `SoapServer` class.

PHP's built-in `SoapServer` class will automatically parse the `SOAP` XML request for you, and turn it into objects you can use in your code.  If you find yourself needing to parse XML manually, you are doing something wrong, and you might be better off using a normal `XML-RPC` style API.

The `URI` field is essentially used for XML namespacing.

The `location` parameter in the `SoapClient` is the web service endpoint.  This is useful if you are consuming a `SOAP` API with multiple endpoints, it allows for specifying the one you want.